# Why can't I think the wavefct solutions $X(x)$, $Y(y)$, $Z(z)$ correspond to the same energy by using the symmetry property of the 3D cube potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

The above is the problem and the following is the solutions, when I separate the variables, I think the potential has $x\leftrightarrow y\leftrightarrow z$ symmetry, so I think the $X$, $Y$, $Z$ all responds to $E/3$. Why can't I think so?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: One could argue that OP is indeed asking a conceptional (as opposed to a HW) question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not for asking homework because I just find somthing more than that problem  when I finish the problem. This is my first time to physics stack exchange,I'm sorry if I break some rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: More generally, if you have a differential equation (DE) that respects a symmetry of a group $G$, it does *not* in general follow that a solution to the DE should also satisfied the same symmetry, i.e. the symmetry could be [spontaneously broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking).